# PHP Array Check the attribute, return value based on attribute

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I am trying to return pull a value based on an attribute from an array, and it seems straight forward enough but I can't seem to nail down the correct way to accomplish this.

Here is the array I am trying to pull from:

```
[1] => InfoOptions Object
            (
            [description] => INFO
            [optSequence] => 2
            [eqpObject] => CUSTOMER NTWK ENG
            [attribute] => 
            [eqpValue] => 
            [dlrSequence] => 10
            )

[2] => InfoOptions Object
           (
            [description] => 
            [optSequence] => 3
            [eqpObject] => CUSTOMER TEST
            [attribute] => CUSTOMER
            [eqpValue] => Jon Doe
            [dlrSequence] => 10
            )
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
if (is_array($provisionCVResult->path->infoOptions-_InfoOptions)) {       
    foreach ($provisionCVResult->path->infoOptions ->InfoOptions as $cv_obj) {
        $CVA = array();
        $result = null;

        foreach ($CV_obj as $value) {
            if($value['attribute'] == 'CUSTOMER') {
                $CVA["eqpValue"] = $cv_obj->eqpValue;
                break;
            }
        }

        $this->cvArrayDataList[] = $CVA;
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell without more of `$provisionCVResult` but `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: what is desired output?

Comment: The $provisionCVResult is returning that array, the desired result is to return 'eqpValue' of 'attribute' when = to Customer

Comment: But it looks like that array is actually `$provisionCVResult->path->InfoOptions`, isn't it? Also, is `$provisionCVResult->path->InfoOptions ->InfoOptions` a typo or is InfoOptions really a property of InfoOptions?

Comment: Unfortunately, InfoOptions is really a property of infoOptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If **$provisionCVResult->path->InfoOptions** is an array, it does not make sense to write  **$provisionCVResult->path->InfoOptions ->InfoOptions** in the **foreach**
   EDIT: I red in the comments that the array is **$provisionCVResult->path->InfoOptions->InfoOptions**
2. PHP is case sensitive so **$cv_obj** and **$CV_obj** are two different variables
3. The second **foreach** is not needed

So, assuming **$provisionCVResult->path->InfoOptions->InfoOptions** is returning an array of *InfoOptions Object*, I think you should do something like this:

```
if (is_array($provisionCVResult->path->InfoOptions->InfoOptions)) 
{

    $result = null;

    foreach($provisionCVResult->path->InfoOptions->InfoOptions as $cv_obj)
    {

        if($cv_obj->attribute == 'CUSTOMER')
        {
            $this->cvArrayDataList[] = array("eqpValue" => $cv_obj->eqpValue);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Based on OP's response in the comments, it sounds like there is another property `InfoOptions` in `InfoOptions` that contains the array.

Comment: Thanks this did it, looks simple now that I see it.

Answer (score 1):

Having a quick look, try changing

```
$value['attribute'] == 'CUSTOMER'
```

To

```
$value->attribute == 'CUSTOMER'
```

As the element is an "InfoOptions object" and not an array.

Note I would also recommend using strict comparison, e.g '===' instead of '=='.